# How to remove root-only access for /var/www files?

Tags: linux, permissions

I have set up a LAMP environment. All of the files that I want to run on the localhost are placed into my /var/www directory. Each time I want to open up a file with write permissions, I have to prefix the command with sudo at the beginning. How do I change the permissions of /var/www so any user other than root can modify the contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to change the ownership to your userid.  This should not be user id the webserver is accessing the files you are using.  Use the `chown` command recursively.  Try a command like:

```
sudo chown -R $LOGNAME /var/www
```

This will recursively change the `/var/www` directory tree to your userid.  `LOGNAME` is normally set to your userid.  This can be verified with the command `echo $LOGNAME`.

Limit write access by the web server to as few directories and files as possible.